# Find in Array then replace or add its value with.png

Tags: php, arrays

here is some commands.

```
$filewithoutext = array("1F621", "1F536", "1F365", "1F33B", "1F193", "0035-20E3");
$changtofilename = str_replace($vowels, ".png", "1F536 1F621");
```

my requirement is if value find **(1F33B 1F193)** then system will change it to **.png** like  **1F536.png 1F621.png**

Comment: Niranjan N Rajuthanks for your edit

Comment: Can you please show us the $vowels data?

Comment: oh sorry my mistake...

Comment: change it to $filewithoutext

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $vowels = array("1C536", "1F621");
    $array = array("1F621", "1F536", "1F365", "1F33B", "1F193", "0035-20E3");
    foreach ($vowels as $key => $val) {
        if (in_array($val, $array)) {
            $key = array_search($val, $array);
            $array[$key] = $array[$key] . ".png";
        }
    }
    print_r($array);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/483761)

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju what if `$vowels` value do not exists in `$array`. plz try it with `$vowels = array("1C536","1F621");`

Comment: I have string something like that

    $string= "hello guyes 1F621 how are you all? 1F536";
    
I want to  change 1F621 and 1F536 to 1F621.png and 1F536.png
so finally my string is hello guyes 1F621.png how are you all? 1F536.png

What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

try below solution:

```
<?php
$vowels = array("1F536", "1F621");
$array = array("1F621", "1F536", "1F365", "1F33B", "1F193", "0035-20E3");

$arr = array_map(function(&$val) use($vowels){
    $value = (in_array($val, $vowels) !== false) ? $val . '.png' : $val;
    return $value;
}, $array);

print_r($arr);
```

`$arr` will have desired result.

Comment: which version of php you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $find = array('1F33B', '1F621');
    $replace = array('1F33B.png', '1F621.png');
    $filewithoutext = array("1F621", "1F536", "1F365", "1F33B", "1F193", "0035-20E3");
    $changtofilename = str_replace($find, $replace, $filewithoutext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) and [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$files = array("1F621", "1F536", "1F365", "1F33B", "1F193", "0035-20E3");
$targets = array("1F536", "1F621");

$filesWithExtensions = array_map(function($item) use ($targets) {
    if (in_array($item, $targets)) {
        $item .= '.png';
    }
    return $item;
}, $files);

print_r($filesWithExtensions);
```

Comment: can you echo fine value with png?

Comment: Done. You can try it now.